# Linux memory overcommit details

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, embedded-linux, low-memory

I am developing SW for embedded Linux and i am suffering system hangs because OOM Killer appears from time to time. Before going beyond i would like to solve some confusing issues about how Linux Kernel allocate dynamic memory assuming /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory has 0 and /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes has 712, and no swap.

Supposing embedded Linux currently physical memory available is 5MB (5MB of free memory and there is not usable cached or buffered memory available) if i write this piece of code:

```c
.....
#define MEGABYTE 1024*1024
.....
.....
void *ptr = NULL;
ptr = (void *) malloc(6*MEGABYTE); //Preserving 6MB
if (!prt) 
    exit(1);
memset(ptr, 1, MEGABYTE);
.....
```

I would like to know if when memset call is committed the kernel will try to allocate ~6MB or ~1MB (or min_free_kbytes multiple) in the physical memory space.

Right now there is about 9MB in my embedded device which has 32MB RAM. I check it by doing

```
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
# free
            total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:        23732        14184         9548            0          220
Swap:            0            0            0
Total:        23732        14184         9548
```

Forgetting last piece of C code, i would like to know if its possible that oom killer appears when for instance free memory is about >6MB. 
I want to know if the system is out of memory when oom appears, so i think i have two options:

- See VmRSS entries in /proc/pid/status of suspicious process.
- Set /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 2 and /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory = 75 and see if there is any process requiring more of physical memory available.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous because it's not clear what you mean by "allocate". The kernel will *reserve* 6MB, but it won't allocate anything yet because the process may never access the memory.

Comment: But when memset(ptr,1,MEGABYTE) is performed the process is writing the memory, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and then the OS has to actually allocate some.

Comment: But my question if it allocate ~6MB or ~1MB?

Comment: It reserves 6MB, then allocates 1MB of that.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can read this [document](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html#ss9.6). Is provides you three small C programs that you can use to understand what happens with the different possible values of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` .