# Fastest way to accept file via pipe in to C++ application on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, performance, unix, optimization

I have a C++ application which reads bytes of data in the form of messages. The messages are stored in a text file, separated by the newline character.

What would be the fastest way to pipe these bytes to the C++ app/accept the bytes from the pipeline within the C++ app?

The answer I am ideally looking for will show how the C++ application accepts the (my guess) std::cin input?

Comment: Constructive criticisms (rather than pointless down-voting) will be much appreciated....

Comment: I don't think I got it. You want to read the file (with cat or something) then pipe the result onto your app?

Comment: I/O performance does not matter that much (usually disk is the bottleneck). And code first a correct program, then profile and benchmark it to understand what should be optimized (asymptotic complexity is often what matters a lot).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no- this is not a "only optimize if needs be". I need to know the fastest mechanism for piping file byte contents in to a C++ application (appreciate you taking the time to reply though).

Comment: @webuster A file containing data will be piped in to a C++ application which will process the data. I am under the impression there is one way of sending the data to the app (piping) but from within the app there are multiple ways of handling the pipe?

Comment: BTW, "*piping* file contents" suggests [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) which is *not* what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve what you want by using [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) which extracts characters from a stream until a delimitation character is found.

Using it on the *standard input stream* would lead to something close to the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int     main() {
  std::string data;

  while (std::getline(std::cin, data)) {
    // each messages would be stored into data
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
  }

  return (0);
}
```

A way to test this sample would be to :

```
cat my_file | ./my_sample [...]
```

Comment: Ok- I know about this approach but is it THE fastest way?! getline() uses strings- which have constructors, which is not good for performance..... is there any way to do this using bytes and minimal copying?

Comment: Well it depends on what you're planning to do exactly. The perfomance delivered by the above constructs should be enough for most use-cases. Now if you'd like to go using pointer to `char` directly as in `C`, you can call the `read` system call directly (e.g `read(0, buffer, size_to_read)` and check for a newline character yourself for each messages. Not sure this would far more efficient than using the STL which does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- I am fairly certain it would be faster because as soon as strings are involved you start getting memory allocation/deallocation happening everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If performance matters that much (which is really unlikely) you could avoid the small overhead of C++ streams and *directly* use Linux or Posix specific [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) to read a file (plain file in a file system, i.e. not a pipe) like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) or [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), and even (in some other thread) [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551572/841108).

<sup>If using `read` (e.g. because reading some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), not a disk file) you probably want to use quite big blocks or buffers, e.g. reading at least 64 kilobytes at once.</sup>

However, the hardware (disk probably) is probably the bottleneck. Consider buying more RAM (to increase filesystem cache) and some SSD. See also [linuxatemyram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) ...

You may want to use several (e.g. 2 to 6)  threads (with [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)) and/or asynchronous I/O; see [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html). I don't think it is worth the effort. Avoid [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) thru synchronization.

Study also the architecture and implementation of high-performance [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) free software mail transfer agents ([MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)) like [exim](http://exim.org/) or [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)... They are dealing quite well with an issue similar to yours.

You will need to benchmark your application to tune parameters.