# how to allocate large arrayes using C in linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, allocation

Is there a way to allocate an array with this size:

```
unsigned long M[2000][900000] ;
```

This is what I get when I run the program (no errors during compilation).

[image]

```
Processus arrêté (Process stopped)
```

Comment: And looking at the shell configuration, he thought he is coding Matrix :D

Comment: Please not that this array would be 6.7GB in size. Do you have that much RAM on your machine?

Comment: That array is at least about 7GB. Do you really need such a large array? Chances are you have deeper problems with your logic/algorithm if you do.

Comment: i need an array with exactly this size ( thnx for your comment but it does not help and yeah i know what malloc is)

Comment: @AlexanderVogt yeah i have more

Comment: A 32 bit binary cannot address 7GB of data. Did you build a 64 bit binary and are you running a 64 bit system?

Comment: @kaylum it's for knapsack problem [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with w=900000 and n=2000

Comment: @kaylum yeah i'm using 64 bits

Comment: Why don't you give this array static storage duration? That should work.

Comment: ↑ Try `static unsigned long M[2000][900000] ;`

Comment: Dude, do you even malloc?

Answer (score 6):

```
unsigned long (*pM)[2000][900000] = malloc(sizeof *pM);
```

does the job.

Use it like this

```
#define ROWS_MAX (2000)
#define COLUMNS_MAX (900000)

...

unsigned long (*pM)[ROWS_MAX][COLUMNS_MAX] = malloc(sizeof *pM);

/* 1st test whether the allocation succeeded! */
if (NULL == pM)
{
  perror("malloc() failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Then initialise the array. */
for (size_t row = 0; row < ROWS_MAX; ++row)
{
  for (size_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS_MAX; ++column)
  {
    (*pM)[row][column] = 42;
  }
}

/* Do something ... */
...

/* Deallocate, free the memory. */
free(pM);
```

An alternative approach using more than one block or memory would be using a scattered/sparse array:

```
unsigned long ** ppM = malloc(ROWS_MAX * sizeof *ppM);
if (NULL == ppM)
{
  perror("malloc() for row pointers failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

for (size_t row = 0; row < ROWS_MAX; ++row)
{
  ppM[row] = malloc(COLUMNS_MAX * sizeof *ppM[row]);
  if (NULL == ppM[row])
  {
    perror("malloc() for a column failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    /* If not exiting the process here (but probably return from the function
       we are in), we need to perform a clean-up on what had been allocated 
       so far. See below code for free()ing it as a hint how to approach this. */
  }
}

/* Then initialise the array. */
for (size_t row = 0; row < ROWS_MAX; ++row)
{
  for (size_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS_MAX; ++column)
  {
    ppM[row][column] = 42; /* Note the difference how to access the array. */
  }
}

/* Do something ... */
...

/* Deallocate, free the memory. */
/* Free columns. */
for (size_t row = 0; row < ROWS_MAX; ++row)
{
  free(ppM[row]);
}

/* Free row pointers. */
free(ppM);
```

Comment: Also with such a `malloc()` checking result is not null seems to me mandatory.

Comment: it does not work : malloc() failed: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: .. or go for a scattered array. Updating my answer.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneMechri: So you want to increase the OS's swap space. Or have a look a what `ulimit` tells you on the currently configured maximum allowed memory per process.

Comment: I think that you meant "Sparse Array", no?

Comment: I am no native English speaker ... would "*Sparse*" be the official jargon, yes?-S @DavidHoelzer

Comment: @alk : max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited

Comment: @AbderrahmaneMechri: Does the 2nd approach as per my answer work? How much swap space does the OS has configured?

Comment: @alk it work but it's block now in the initialisation i have the same message error : process stopped is there any timeout or something like this ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneMechri: It looks as if the blocks to be alocated are still to large. You either want to get more RAM, or make up different data structure to hold those  2000 * 900000 * 8 byte (per `unsigned long`) = 14GBytes!

Comment: @AbderrahmaneMechri: For the reason why it errors during initialisation and not during allocation you might like to read here: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html#ss9.6 (found the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148296/linux-memory-overcommit-details) How to steer over-commiting behaviour on Linux you want to have look here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

Comment: And again: How much swap space does the OS has configured?